# MS Access - using multiple "number format" criteria in DSUM

Tags: ms-access, expression

I am trying to calculate a running total using DSum in MS Access relying on two criteria. I believe I have my quotes in the criteria portion of the expression in the wrong places. This is the current version of the expression, entered in the "Control Source" of my text box:

```
=DSum("[WBSValue]","[qWBSbyInv]","[ID]< &[ID] And [WBS]=" &[WBS])
```

Both [ID] and [WBS] are numbers (not text or date). I have checked that each one works correctly by itself in a DSum:

`=DSum("[WBSValue]","[qWBSbyInv]"," [ID] <" &[ID])` ---> correctly returns a running total based on ID (but that is the same for every WBS)

`=DSum("[WBSValue]","[qWBSbyInv]", "[WBS] =" & [WBS])` ---> correctly returns a total for each WBS (but that is not a running total)

I'm struggling to understand how to combine the two criteria with AND.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate both values to the criteria, like this:

```
=DSum("[WBSValue]","[qWBSbyInv]","[ID]<" & [ID] & " And [WBS]=" & [WBS])
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! My only previous experience with multiple criteria in Dsum was with one number and one text field, so I was defaulting to that syntax as my starting point. Appreciate the assistance!